# How to set max_bad_records as 100% in BigQuery while loading data into tables from csv files?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, greenplum

I have the code for putting files from docker to Greenplum

```
copy table_1 from '/home/gpadmin/temp/file.csv'
with (format csv, DELIMITER ',', quote '"', header)
SEGMENT REJECT LIMIT 100 PERCENT;
```

I am trying to load csv files into bq tables and this is the code I am currently using:

```
bq -q load \
--source_format=CSV  --field_delimiter="," --skip_leading_rows=1 --max_bad_records=999999999 \
dataset_1.table_1 \
gs://bucket_name/folder/file.csv
```

I want to replicate segment reject limit 100 percent in BigQuery to load the data correctly.